# A function which is not in $L^1((0,1))$ but whose derivative is in $L^1((0,1))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I'm looking for an absolutely continuous function $f : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ s.t. $f \not \in L^1 $ but $f' \in L^1$.

Notice that if the definition interval of $f$ would be $(0, \infty)$ then $1/x$ would be an example. But how can I build such an example on $(0,1)$?

Comment: There is no such example. It's easy to see from the definition that any function absolutely continuous on $(0,1)$ is bounded...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Of course, thank you. What if I replace the absolute continuity requirement with "differentiable almost everywhere"?

Comment: "differentiable almost everywhere" is such a weak condition it's very easy to get. But it's also more or less useless. Hmm. Say $a_n$ decreases to $0$. Let $I_n={(a_{n+1},a_n)}$. Let $(c_n)$ be any sequence of constants, and let $f=\sum c_n\chi_{I_n}$. That gives the example you asked for, but probably not the example you wanted...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I guess it's $c_n$ in such a way to make $f \not \in L^1$ (one can just take a piecewise constant version of $1/x$). Anyway thank you, I'm quite satisfied by this example